# Device BackButton is Working first time

Tags: javascript, android

Whenever I got to the homepage.html page, the first time backbutton event works because I have overridden backbutton event listener.

After going to any other page, like myquery.html, and from that page go back again to homepage.html, backbutton event doesn't work. I have the same problem in all HTML pages: backbutton event only works the first time, but I have no errors in my logcat.

Here is the code:

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{ 
    // Now safe to use the Cordova API 
    /* Registering the basic events associated with device hardware */ 
    document.addEventListener("backbutton",backKeyDown, false); 
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", function() 
        { 
        //Handle the menu button 
        $("#utilsMenu").click(); 
        }, false); 
}
function backKeyDown(event){
alert("back ..")
    //Handle the back button
    $("#back").click();
```

}

Comment: html means xml? and please post some code

Comment: function onDeviceReady() {
 // Now safe to use the Cordova API
 /* Registering the basic events associated with device hardware */
 
 document.addEventListener("backbutton",backKeyDown, false);
 
 document.addEventListener("menubutton", function() {
  //Handle the menu button
  $("#utilsMenu").click();
 }, false);
 }

Comment: its Html Page @ Pier

Comment: ok now i got it, i edited the question for a better comprehension  but i can't help you sorry, not expert of crosplatform ;)

Comment: Have you added the event listener for deviceready? `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false)`

Comment: only first time backkeydown() fires